# Insert blank lines in kable

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm tabling groups of rows in a kable. Each group contains data for one group, with between 3 and 5 rows per group. I want to leave blank lines in the table between groups for readability, but can't get it to work. 
I put in a row of all NA, and then set options(knitr.kable.NA=""). This works OK when printed in the console, as here:

```
|C.01.C.00522 |        3|        1203|    0.043|                -0.096|           -16.441|
|C.01.C.00522 |        4|        8364|    0.298|                 0.159|            31.765|
|C.01.C.00522 |        5|        3494|    0.124|                -0.014|            -2.588|
|             |         |            |         |                      |                  |
|C.02.A.00577 |        1|        2496|    0.089|                -0.014|            -2.410|
|C.02.A.00577 |        2|        1975|    0.070|                -0.032|            -5.609|
|C.02.A.00577 |        3|        3400|    0.121|                 0.018|             3.297|
```

But in the rendered pdf document there one table for the first group, and then all unformatted lines after that.

C.01.C.00522 3 1203 0.043 -0.096 -16.441 C.01.C.00522 4 8364 0.298 0.159 31.765 C.01.C.00522 5 3494 0.124
-0.014 -2.588
C.02.A.00577 1 2496 0.089 -0.014 -2.410 C.02.A.00577 2 1975 0.070 -0.032 -5.609

I also tried options(knitr.kable.NA='.') and this produces a properly formatted table, but all the dots are a little annoying.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you haven't seen this already, `group_rows` function of  [kableExtra](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/0.2.1) might help in improving the readability and grouping of rows

Comment: I don't think this is practical. It seems `group_rows` only does one group at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you Imran for mentioning kableExtra. In `kableExtra` 0.3 which I released last week, a new function called `collapse_rows` may do some help in this case.

```
dt <-data.frame(id =c(rep("C.01.C.00522", 3),rep("C.02.A.00577", 3)),var1 =c(3,4,5,1,2,3), var2 =c(1203, 8364, 3494, 2496, 1975, 3400))

kable(dt, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1)
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thanks, Hao. This seems like just what I need. However, I'm getting pandoc error 43, with this message:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.125 \toprule
Here's the code that calls kable:
    kable(all.tabs, "latex", booktabs=T, caption=paste("Distractor Statistics 
    for", assessment, yrq))  %>%
        collapse_rows(columns=1)

Comment: @Stuart Interesting. Can you post an issue on https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues with a reproducible example & your session info if possible so I can track down what's going on?

Comment: I found out that I needed to add some \usepackage{} statements in the YAML header, like this:
    header-includes:
       - \usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
       - \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
       - \usepackage{enumitem, array}
not sure if I needed all of these, but....
But the table is longer than 1 page, but it doesn't do the \longtable thing. It just stops, even though a regular kable() works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stuart If you load `kableExtra` using `library(kableExtra)` instead of calling `kableExtra::collapse_rows()`, it will load necessary package for you by default. For longtable, you can use the `longtable` option in `kable` to do that. like `kable(dt, "latex", longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = "repeat_header") %>% collapse_rows()`

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for your help and for the kableExtra package! However, I still had to add the latex \usepackages{} in the YAML header, even though I loaded kableExtra using library(). Actually, I've got a little R program that does the rendering, and the library(kableExtra) is there. I don't have library(kableExtra) in the Rmd document. That shouldn't make a different, should it?

Comment: That's an interesting finding. Actually, it does matter since it needs to be pumped into the rmd environment

Comment: That's unexpected. I'll try it and let you know what happens.